# Update does not work sometime in sqlite table

Tags: android, sqlite

I am developing a location tracking android app. Getting location in every 10 sec and inserted to sqlite database location table and every 1 minute sync with server database. After sync success, I have updated the location table as sync 1. It's working fine for two or three hours-after that the location table does not update properly. Is there any update limit?
Am I doing something wrong please help!

**Code sample**

```
 SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            if (db != null) {
                db.beginTransaction();
                Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

                cv.put(DB_TABLE.tbl_VehicleLiveMovementDetail_IsSync, 1);
                db.update(DB_TABLE.tbl_VehicleLiveMovementDetail, cv, "IsSync !=" + 1, null);
                db.setTransactionSuccessful();
                db.endTransaction();
                db.close(); // Closing database connection
                cv.clear();

                return true;
            }
```

Comment: why not keep clearing your table after success.

Comment: I will clear data after every 7 days.

Comment: What does "not update properly mean"?. There is no direct update limit. However, there is the potential to hit the maximum depth of TRIGGER recursion. Why are you getting the time but not using it?

Comment: Why not use `int rv = db.update(.......` along with `return rv > 0;` (i.e. rv will be 0 if nothing was updated else 1 or more). Seems useless to always return true.

Comment: I can not use TRIGGER. Because i have to update location table sync as 1 when sent data to server successfully. And it may need my specified time or any time (when only wifi or mobile data found). @mikeT

Comment: Yes, it's good idea. But still problem is not solved, because i already sync with server and i have to sync location table. Another location data inserting everything 10 sec. So if i trying to sync repeatedly then un-sync data will sync as 1 and i lost it sync with server. Thanks @mikeT

Comment: I didn't say use a TRIGGER. I said the only real limitation upon the number of updates would be TRIGGER recursion depth. You have also not explained what "not update properly" means. i.e. what is the actual problem (what is or is not happening and what should happen) rather than just saying that you have a problem.

Comment: Put it this way you appear to be saying update the **Details** table by changing the value of the **IsSync** column to **1** where the **IsSync** column **is not 1** (***so every row will now have 1 in the IsSync column***). Unless new rows are added to the **Detail** table there will then be **no updates to perform** as **all rows** have **1** in the **IsSync** column.

Comment: Yes, all row will IsSync=1. Before sync with server it's treat as  IsSync=0, After sync i updated all rows IsSync=1. Next time wouldn't send these rows because i already have these rows. 
Hey, The problem is occurred when my phone goes in sleep mode. @mikeT

Comment: At a guess you need to be running the above in a service or incorporating it into a service rather than in an App. [Services overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services)

Comment: Yes, I am using foreground service and having same problem.